# Troubles with Implementation of self written Module for Joomla and Auto Suggest function which should be in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, module, joomla

I am trying to find a way to implement either a self written module in Joomla with PHP code of an dictionary or try to use the dictionary by putting the PHP code in a joomla article with sourcerer plugin. I am really new in Joomla and PHP. Could someone help?

1. How could I add a Javascript Code in order to get an AutoSuggest Function as a dropdown list to get suggestions for words when I start typing?
2. How to get this code into Joola files and install it as module?

I am trying this since days and can't go further. Here is the code which I wrote until now:

```
{source}<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Dictionary</title> 
    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <style>
    body {
    font-family: Arial;
    }
    
    * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    form.example input[type=text]  {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 17px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    float: left;
    width: 80%;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    
    border-radius: 4px;
    }
    
    form.example button {
    
    border-radius: 4px;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    padding: 3.6px;
    background: #17558c
    ;
    color: white;
    font-size: 17px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-left: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    form.example button:hover {
    background: #0b7dda;
    }
    
    form.example::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
    }     
    
    body {
    }
    
    $brand-primary: #09c;
    $brand-gray: #ccc;
    
    .menubar {
    height: 230px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid $brand-gray;
    }     
    
    .panel {
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: none;
    background-color: $brand-primary;
    }
    
    .panel .panel-heading {
    padding: 1px 12px;
    }
    
    .panel .panel-body {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin: 0px 6px 6px 6px;
    min-height: 200px;
    }
    
    p.ex1 {
    padding-left: 10px;
    }
    
    p.ex2 {
    padding-left: 20px;
    }
    
    </style>
    
    
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <form class="example"  style="margin:auto;max-width:300px" method = "post">
    
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search" >
    
       <button type="submit" name="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    
    </form>
    
    </body>
    </html>
    
    <?php
    
    
    $con = new PDO("mysql:testhosting;dbname=testdb",'testuser','testpassword');
    
    
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $str = $_POST["search"];
    $sth = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM `dictionary` WHERE wort = '$str'");
    
    $sth->setFetchMode(PDO:: FETCH_OBJ);
    $sth -> execute();
    
    if($row = $sth->fetch())
    {
    ?>
    
    <br> <br>   
    
    <div class="container"> 
    <div class="panel panel-primary"> 
    
    <div class="panel-heading"><h4><b><?php echo $row->wort;?></b></h4></div>
    
    <div class="panel-body"><h5><b><i><?php echo $row->form2;?>
    
    <?php echo $row->form3;?></i></b></h5></p> 
    
    
    <?php echo $row->setz1;?>
    
    <?php echo $row->setz2;?>
    
    <?php echo $row->setz3;?>
    
    <?php echo $row->setz4;?> 
    
    <?php echo $row->setz5;?>
    
    <?php echo $row->setz6;?>     
    
    <?php echo $row->setz7;?>
    
    <?php echo $row->setz8;?>
    
    <?php echo $row->setz9;?> 
    
    <?php echo $row->setz10;?>
    
    </div>
    </div>
    
    </div>     
    
    </p>     
    
    <?php
    
    }
    else{
    
    
    echo "<br> The searched word is not given in our database.";
    }
    }
    ?>  
    
{/source}
```

Thank you in advance for your support and sorry for the long text!

Comment: sidenote: joomla questions can also be asked on [joomla.stackexchange.com](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks @berend I posted it also there.

Comment: Is here nobody who could help out in this issue?